# How does a linear momentum transfer to angular momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, momentum

What if i have a system consisting a rod with 2 balls with same mass at both of the end, if a  third ball fall into one of the balls on the rod with a speed $v$ and mass $m$, suppose the third ball stick to the one of the balls,how does the linear momentum of the third ball transfer to the system angular momentum?

Answer (score 2):

The third ball already had angular momentum. You do not need to be rotating or moving in a circle to have angular momentum.  If you calculate angular momentum $\vec H$ from linear momentum $\vec p$ and position $\vec r$ from a center via

$$\vec H = \vec r \times \vec p$$

$$=|\vec r||\vec p|\sin \theta ~~\hat z$$

you'll find that it does not change, even if the 3rd ball did not hit anything and continued in a straight line.

It's not that linear momentum is converted into angular. $\vec p$ and $\vec H$ are conserved independently.

The 3rd ball's linear momentum is altered in your scenario by the axis of the rod exerting a force (upward).